# Can I change location of application.ini in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, configuration-files

For now **application.ini** is in following folder of my project:

```
projectfolder/application/configs/application.ini
```

For some reason I have to move this to

```
projectfolder/application.ini
```

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the ***index.php***, you can set the path when you instant the object of `Zend_Application`

```
 $application = new Zend_Application(
        APPLICATION_ENV,
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/mynewpath/application.ini'
    );
```